# How to create Af:Table with Search and button From method Exposed in the ADF DataControl?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have a Java Method That Take A String Parameter And Return a DTO

and this method is exposed in the data Control

I'm trying to drag the method into my page fragment to generate An af:table
but the only showed options is Paramter Or Method 
is there a way to generate a inputText , SearchButton , and a table
by simply drag this method to the JSFF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drag a View Object element to generate a table, input text and a View Criteria to implement a Search in jsf.

To have your view object based on the result of your Java method you can :

- Create a View object
- Generate it's Java class
- Add your java logic into the ViewObject Impl constructor.

Your java logic will then be call everytime the table is constructed.